# In C#, can I do "this = ..." outside of a constructor?

Tags: c#

Basically, can I do this, and what actually happens?

```
public class foo
{
    public int id;

    public void bar()
    {
        //do stuff

        this = null;    // ?
        //do stuff
        foo[] all = otherclass.FindAllFoos();
        foreach(foo f in all)
        {
            if(f.id == 42)
            {
                this = f;    // ?
                break;
            }
        }

        //do stuff
    }
};
```

Some specific background that shouldn't matter:

The real project has a class that represents a USB device that I'm currently talking to, and just before this point in the program, I tell the device to reboot.  When the device comes back, it appears different enough to invalidate this instance, so I have to find it again among all the connected devices and continue talking to it.

Comment: Actually, the background matters enormously.  It tells us what you are trying to accomplish, and allows us to offer alternatives (although you haven't provided quite enough detail for that to happen).  Generally, you set an object to null from the outside of an object.  You cannot do so from the inside for the same reasons that teeth can't bite themselves, and a snake can't eat its own tail.

Comment: I figured it was a bad idea in general, but possible if you know what you're doing enough to avoid the pitfalls.  (for example, all of the variables may have changed without the optimizer realizing it)  I think the method should continue executing code until it returns normally or throws an exception, but would the simple act of modifying 'this' throw that exception?

Comment: You can say `this.something = value;`.  You cannot say `this = null`.  An object cannot invalidate itself in this way.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I just got to V.Studio, and tried to build it.  It says, "Cannot assign to '<this>' because it is read-only".

Comment: AaronD that's unlikely, as @RobertHarvey [wrote this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265458/839601) about questions like your

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was useful.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you cannot make an instance set itself to null.  `this = null;` will not work.  The functions and data that are defined inside of a class "live" in that classes instance.  If the instance is destroyed, everything associated with it is destroyed.

The `bar()` method should be moved into a different class, and manipulate `foo` classes.  For example:

```
public class FooManipulator
{
    private Foo _myFoo;

    public void bar()
    {
        var allTheFoos = otherClass.FindAllFoos();
        foreach(foo f in all)
        {
            if(f.id == 42)
            {
                this._myFoo = f;
                break;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this=null`

You cannot assign to `this`, it's read only for classes.

You can assign to `this` for a struct, but then a struct can't be null because its a value type.

Try putting it in an [IDE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?